# Query parents without children

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a menu table and I am struggling to select all parent-menus without a child.

```
SELECT  
CASE 
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) children
       FROM menu
       WHERE cod_idiom = 'EN'
       START WITH cod_menu_parent = m1.cod_menu
       CONNECT BY PRIOR cod_menu = cod_menu_parent ) = 0 THEN
      cod_menu
END x
FROM menu m1
WHERE m1.isSubMenu = 'T'
```

*isSubMenu = 'T' means it might (should) have children which may be a sub-menu or a file.

The idea was to first query all sub-menus, get their menu code and then do a CONNECT BY PRIOR to count its children.

The above query didn't have the expected effect, do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Technically, `isSubMenu` is a derived field, which are generally frowned on in more-normalized databases; you may wish to remove it, or be forced to keep it in sync (not a pretty task).  In addition, the field name sounds like it belongs on the other side of the relationship (that it is a child field, rather than having them).  If your description of the field usage is correct, consider changing the name to `hasSubMenu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m1.cod_menu
    FROM menu m1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                         FROM MENU m2 
                         WHERE m1.cod_menu = m2.cod_menu_parent)
        AND m1.isSubMenu = 'T'
```